# angular-cli beta 14 - How to import Environment?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I just updated to the latest angular-cli (beta 14) which now uses webpack instead of systemjs.

I used to be able to import constants from the `config/environment{prod|dev}.ts` by simply importing it à la `import { BASE_URL } from '../environment'`. This doesn't work any more.
Environments are now defined in `angular-cli.json` and point to `environments/environment{.prod}.ts` but how do I access them in my components?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply import in the `environment.ts` file and at build time the appropriate environments file will be supplied based upon the environment (dev/prod)

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```

Comment: I had tried this in all possible variations but for some reason it only worked after I had the `ng serve` restarted... Thx though for confirming the correct notation!

Comment: Worked for me too after a restart of `ng serve`